# Bind Listview to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, binding, observablecollection

I am trying to bind a listview to an ObservableCollection.

I took a look at several topics on stack, but cannot find what I am doing wrong :

My XAML looks like that (for GridViewColumn I tried both wih Path=, and without, as I saw both of them) :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1"  ItemsSource="{Binding listeAff}"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" >
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="Context1">
                    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.ContextSupprimer}" Click="Supprimer_Element"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuBarNesting" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.ContextMiseEnBarre}" Click="Open_MiseEnBarre"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuExportDSTV1" Header="{x:Static  p:Resources.ContextExport}" Click="Export_DSTV"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="AjouterAffaire" Header="{x:Static  p:Resources.AjouterAffaire}" Click="AjoutAffaire"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ModifyAffaire" Header="{x:Static  p:Resources.Edit}" Click="ModifierAffaire"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.View>

                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" x:Name="GridView1">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding= "{Binding Nom}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Nom}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Code}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Comm}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Commentaire}"/>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Then code behind is so :

```
public ObservableCollection<Affaire> listeAff { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.Langue);
            InitializeComponent();
            Initialisation();
            listeAff = new ObservableCollection<Affaire>();
            DBConnect DataBase = new DBConnect();
            string requete = "SELECT * FROM affaire ORDER BY ID";
            List<Affaire> liste = DataBase.Select_affaire(requete);
            foreach(Affaire aff in liste)
            {
                listeAff.Add(aff);
            }
            DataContext = this;
```

On that part my ListView is shown correctly, but when I want to delete(for example) some objects in list, listview is not updated :

```
foreach (Affaire aff in ListView1.SelectedItems)
                    {
                        listeAff.Remove(aff);
                    }
```

What did I miss?

Comment: are you getting any rows here List<Affaire> liste = DataBase.Select_affaire(requete); , can you please check in debugging

Comment: so yes, I reeturn some rows, and also the list is updated, but as mentioned Monish Koyott, I don't have any InotifyPropertyChanged (first time I try ObservableCollections), I am trying to implement it, but it is not an easy thing :)

Comment: Can you please try databinding as I suggested,  DataContext = this; means you are assigning datacontext to your window in which you listview present

Comment: Updated my answer , how to implement NotifyPropertyChanged..have look

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: just saw your modify, I will try it(but takes a bit of time as I need to modify all), so XAML I leave it as it was?

Comment: no need to change much , just add INotifyPropertyChanged interface and add property as is ...

Comment: well, now it is not working at all ^^'

Comment: Well first I will try to understand what you wrote... after I will see, cause as I am new to it, I think I cannot go further until I really understand mechanism of all these collection/Ievents... thanks anyway for your help

Comment: ok have a look to INotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableCollection , if you find answer helpfull than upvote/accept it

Comment: let me know if you want tutorial link for that

Comment: would be welcome thanks, because Microsoft link is not very helpfull...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do as below for getting updated values

```
public class ChangeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged=delegate {};

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String 
                                                  propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new 
                 PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Affaire> affaireListObservable;
    public ObservableCollection<Affaire> AffaireListObservable {
      get { return affaireListObservable; }
      set {
        affaireListObservable= value;
        if(PropertyChanged!=null) {
          NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
      }
    }    
    public ChangeViewModel()
    {
        AffaireListObservable  = new ObservableCollection<Affaire>();
    }
    public void RemoveFromList()
    {
         foreach (Affaire aff in ListView1.SelectedItems)
         {
              AffaireListObservable.Remove(aff);
         }
    }
}
```

Double check you binding , As you are assigning DataContext to widnow, than you can go up in tree till window and use it , and bind you listview to DataContext of window

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.listeAff ,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
   Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" 
  />
```

Comment: tried that one, but result is the same. What is this FallbackValue=BindingFailed supposed to do?

Comment: @Siegfried.V - if you are getting data than your binding is fine , so no need to try out my biding part but I suggest you make use of InotifyPropertyCahnged interface in you code and check items got remvoed or not

Comment: Thanks (even if I am late), last days I read some courses to first be able to make binding of simple lists... and this part from you is just what I needed to bind lists between each other :)

Comment: I still meet a problem, I Edit original message to make it more clear, as original one was pretty "wrong"

Comment: I decided to post a new question, to make something more "clean"... I just finished to post question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748369/cascade-binding-on-observablecollection-containing-other-observablecollection

Answer (score 2):

Once you delete or remove something from the collection, the UI has to be notified about it so that it updates itself accordingly. What you have to do is use **INotifyPropertyChanged** event in your class. You can learn all you want about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Happy learning and happy coding !!

Comment: just for information, all is solved, just needed to add this INotifyPropertyChanged ans it all worked, thanks

Comment: Great !! Glad I could be of help to you.